# Finding triples based on multiple subjects (SANSA-STACK)

Tags: rdf, jena, triples, sansa

I have a code to find Triples using a subject,So I am using Triple's find method and supplying the necessary like this :

```
  import net.sansa_stack.rdf.spark.model._

  val node1 = NodeFactory.createURI("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Charles_Dickens")
  val result: RDD[graph.Triple] = triplesRdd.find(Some(node1), None, None)
```

But how can I find a result where I can pass multiple Subject Nodes ?

```
  val node1 = NodeFactory.createURI("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Charles_Dickens")
  val node2 = NodeFactory.createURI("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Henry_James")
  val nodes = List(node1, node2)

  //Here I want to pass list of Subject notes
  val result = triplesRdd.find(Some(node2),None,None)
```

Comment: untested but out of my mind I'd say do `triplesRdd.filter(t => nodes.contains(t.getSubject))`

Comment: yes @UninformedUser that will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code and check if it helps,

```
  val node1 = NodeFactory.createURI("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Charles_Dickens")
  val node2 = NodeFactory.createURI("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Henry_James")
  val nodes = List(node1, node2)

  //Just use filter instead of find ,it will create new RDD containing only items matching those provided subjects
  val result = tripleRDD.filter(triple => nodes.contains(triple.getSubject))
  result.toDF().show(1000,truncate = false)
```